# Adding Web API as Application to Website in IIS, where does Frontend point to?

Tags: reactjs, .net, iis, localhost

I have two separate processes running for my website. The frontend is reactjs and the backend is asp.net core 6.

I have a reactjs website running on localhost:9000 on IIS on a server.

I've added the .net web api published files to the above website as an application with it's own application pool.

[image]
[image]

In the .env REACT_APP_API_URL: I don't know how to point to the API, before i just used localhost:5000, how do I change this to use the application url?

Tried: */api/controllername, localhost/api/controllername, IPADDRESS/api/controllername,
COMPUTERNAME/api/controllername etc.

Here is the Program.cs

```
using api;
using api.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseIIS();

builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
            options =>
            {
                options.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "Project.Cookies";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbDataContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IProjectService, ProjectService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Here is the web.config for the backend:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: -->
```

And here is the web.config for the reactjs frontend:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm in over my head on how to get these talking to each other.

I can run the dotnet from the commandline and have reactjs talk to that localhost on the server (this wont work when connecting to the website from outside the server). But I need these working in IIS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the Bindings settings for your two IIS applications? what ports are defined? do you use the port after the hostname in your react URL?

Comment: @Siraf There are only bindings for the frontend website, the backend application doesn't have a bindings option in the menu.   HTTP unassigned 9000, no host name#

Comment: The two icons you have marked in you screenshot are different. The first icon (which looks like a world) is an IIS application, which means it has an application pool.
The second icon beneath it is different, that is the icon of a virtual directory which don't have bindings.
You must deploy your Web API to an IIS Application, not an IIS Virtual Directory

Comment: You have to exclude the API application from your site level rewrite rule, "React Routes". And then Web API URL will start to work (based on site bindings).

Comment: @Siraf - the api won't be access externally, just the frontend, its only purpose is for the Reactjs app to communicate with it. I thought a virtual directory would be ideal.

Comment: @LexLi - How do I do this?

Comment: There are several ways to exclude URLs, and personally I prefer to add another rule, https://halfblood.pro/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f

Answer (score 0):

The front end and the backend application should use same port. In your react project, you should use something like `const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');` or `process.env.PORT`. And your frontend will start with port which you create the main website. You can find it like below.

[image]

The main application and virtual application host in same site with different application. And they also should use same port. You can check my test result.

[image]

And you can open the frontend application by clicking the `Browse *:8031` in the right panel in my picture.

You can access your api application via `https://localhost:8031/api/{apiname or controller/action}`.

In your case, it should be `http://localhost:port/{hidden by red pen}api/controllername`.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON. I tried setting the PORT like you said but got an error saying URL couldn't be built - REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:9000/API
PORT=9000 gets referenced by export const apiUrl = process.env.PORT; then /api/controller is appended.