HttpOnly cookie received in "Response Cookies" but does not get copied to browser Cookies
This is a dev environment. I am running the backend API (dotnet) from https://localhost:5001, and the front end (nextjs/react) from http://localhost:3000. A login request is sent to the back end, it generates a JWT sends it as an HttpOnly cookie in the response header, which is received successfully by the front end.
Response Headers from DevTools:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:   true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:        http://localhost:3000
Content-Type:                       application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:                               Wed, 15 May 2024 11:44:42 GMT
Server:                             Kestrel
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjpbIkRlcnJpY2suR3VudGVyQGNhbmhzLmNhIiwiQ3VzdG9tT2JqZWN0Q2FuQmVBZGRlZEhlcmUiXSwibmJmIjoxNzE1NzczNDgzLCJleHAiOjE3MTYzNzgyODMsImlhdCI6MTcxNTc3MzQ4M30.F9gep20hb2cv3w4En1TS0hSKXG8ibJaMf9FwOMmgpLw; expires=Wed, 22 May 2024 11:44:43 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Vary:                               Origin

The "token" cookie has properties:
expires=Wed, 22 May 2024 11:44:43 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly

However, the browser never stores it in the Cookies. The "token" is not listed in Cookies for http://localhost:3000 in the Applications tab.
The frontend creates the request like this, using axios:
static readonly apiNoAuthInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL,      // https://localhost:5001/v1/api/
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
  }
});
static apiNoAuth() {
  return APIService.apiNoAuthInstance;
}
...
const response = await APIService.apiNoAuth().post(`token`, {
    "username": user,
    "password": pass
})

The backend has CORS set like this:
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
       builder =>
       {
           builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .AllowCredentials()
                  .AllowAnyMethod();
       });
}

with the header set like this:
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", result.AccessToken,
    new CookieOptions
    {
        Expires = result.ValidTo,
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = true,
        IsEssential = true,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
    });

I think the problem is related to the different back/front IPs but thought that this configuration should work around that. Why is the browser not setting that cookie? Is there a way to get it to? As far as I understand, this won't be an issue in production, but I need to be able to test it locally.

Please [edit] your question to include your client-side code. From a quick glance, it looks like you're including Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the request which is very wrong. Also, please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Also from this answer... "It's very important that you use the relevant credentials options in ALL requests. One common pattern I see on Stack Overflow is forgetting to include it on the initial login request."

@Phil This was it. Adding withCredentials: true in the axios.create() solved the issue.

@Phil Could you explain or point me to the explanation on why including Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the request is very wrong.

CORS headers are for the server's response to a preflight check.   The browser will send the preflight check when it is cross-site.  (It does this all on its own, your request is separate)  The server responds with CORS headers if it wants to allow a cross origin request.  The request never sends those headers.  Btw, different ports would be considered different domains for the browser's CORS rules... but for cookies I think the port does not matter.  (unless you set it explicitly when setting the cookie?)

@Derrick see this post for a full explanation

Hi Derrick, thanks for Phil's comments and suggestions, but for your case, I still think using same domain can help you fix the issue, you can check the answer below and give it a try.

Why is the browser not setting that cookie?
Answer: Please check the doc first. Cookie vs Same Origin Policy
               To put it simply, localhost:3000 and localhost:5001 both use localhost, but they belong to two sites,       a.com and b.com.
If you want to make it works, you should use frontend.a.com and backend.a.com, then they will share the cookies. a means your a domain.
Solution
There are two ways to solve this problem, the simplest is SPA, and the other is to deploy an application using IIS and use a virtual application implementation to open two websites with the same domain name.
1.SPA
Here is a detailed steps for Angular, the steps are same, you can check it.

How to prevent a 404 error when refreshing an angular application that has already been published to IIS 10
2.Virtual Application
Here is a detailed steps for visual application.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974878/7687666
